# Set size of JTable in JScrollPane and in JPanel with the size of the JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, preferredsize

I want the table with the same width as the frame and also when I resize the frame the table need to be resized too. I think `setSize()` of `JTable` doesn't work correctly. Can you help me?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public Main() {
        setSize(400, 600);
        String[] columnNames = {"A", "B", "C"};
        Object[][] data = {
            {"Moni", "adsad", 2},
            {"Jhon", "ewrewr", 4},
            {"Max", "zxczxc", 6}
        };

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        JScrollPane tableSP = new JScrollPane(table);

        int A = this.getWidth();
        int B = this.getHeight();

        table.setSize(A, B);
        JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel();
        tablePanel.add(tableSP);
        tablePanel.setBackground(Color.red);

        add(tablePanel);
        setTitle("Marks");

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                Main ex = new Main();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all: There is no need to add JScrollPane on your JPanel. Second: Don't call setSize(); at all, call pack();.

Comment: I thank you might like to have read through [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

Answer (score 19):

have look at

```
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
```

for the code you posted here

Answer (score 8):

Get rid of all the `setSize` calls. Then get rid of the `tablePanel` and just at the `tableSP` directly to the content pane of the `JFrame`.

The content pane of a `JFrame` has by default a `BorderLayout`, and adding a component to the `BorderLayout#CENTER` (which is the default when you simply use `add` without constraints) will make sure the component takes the size of the parent container.

Quickly adjusted your code

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

    public Main() {
        String[] columnNames = {"A", "B", "C"};
        Object[][] data = {
            {"Moni", "adsad", 2},
            {"Jhon", "ewrewr", 4},
            {"Max", "zxczxc", 6}
        };

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        JScrollPane tableSP = new JScrollPane(table);
        tableSP.setPreferredSize( 400, 600 );

        add(tableSP);
        setTitle("Marks");

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                Main ex = new Main();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Small side-note: there is no reason to extend `JFrame`. Just use one

Comment: never to setPreferredSize for JTable (e.g.) in JScrollpane :-)

Comment: @mKorbel I set the preferred size of the `JScrollPane`. I thought this was one of the few valid use-cases where you could call `setXXXSize`. How else would it determine its size and not just start showing scrollbars ?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, use `GridLayout` for your `tablePanel` and `pack()` the enclosing `Window`.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public Main() {
        String[] columnNames = {"A", "B", "C"};
        Object[][] data = {
            {"Moni", "adsad", 2},
            {"Jhon", "ewrewr", 4},
            {"Max", "zxczxc", 6}
        };

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        JScrollPane tableSP = new JScrollPane(table);

        int A = this.getWidth();
        int B = this.getHeight();

        table.setSize(A, B);
        JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
        tablePanel.add(tableSP);
        tablePanel.setBackground(Color.red);

        add(tablePanel);
        setTitle("Marks");

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                Main ex = new Main();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    JTable table = new JTable();
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{},new String[]{"A","B","C"});
    public Main() {
        super("Mark");
        table.setModel(model);
        add(new JScrollPane(table));

   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                Main ex = new Main();
                ex.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                ex.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                ex.pack();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Quite simplified, but same. :)